# compiling and iterating over a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm fairly new to python, and am working on building a dictionary from a file, and then iterating over the dictionary. I have been working in eclipse, and am not getting any output, or even any warnings.

The input look like this (actual input significantly larger)

```
[Term]
id: GO:0000010
name: trans-hexaprenyltranstransferase activity
namespace: molecular_function
def: "Catalysis of the reaction: all-trans-hexaprenyl diphosphate + isopentenyl diphosphate = all-trans-heptaprenyl diphosphate + diphosphate." [KEGG:R05612, RHEA:20839]
subset: gosubset_prok
xref: KEGG:R05612
xref: RHEA:20839
is_a: GO:0016765 ! transferase activity, transferring alkyl or aryl (other than methyl) groups

[Term]
id: GO:0000011
name: vacuole inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The distribution of vacuoles into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between vacuoles and the cytoskeleton." [GOC:mcc, PMID:10873824, PMID:14616069]
is_a: GO:0007033 ! vacuole organization
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance

[Term]
id: GO:0000012
name: single strand break repair
namespace: biological_process
def: "The repair of single strand breaks in DNA. Repair of such breaks is mediated by the same enzyme systems as are used in base excision repair." [http://www.ultranet.com/~jkimball/BiologyPages/D/DNArepair.html]
subset: gosubset_prok
is_a: GO:0006281 ! DNA repair

[Term]
id: GO:0000014
name: single-stranded DNA endodeoxyribonuclease activity
namespace: molecular_function
def: "Catalysis of the hydrolysis of ester linkages within a single-stranded deoxyribonucleic acid molecule by creating internal breaks." [GOC:mah]
synonym: "single-stranded DNA specific endodeoxyribonuclease activity" RELATED []
synonym: "ssDNA-specific endodeoxyribonuclease activity" RELATED [GOC:mah]
is_a: GO:0004520 ! endodeoxyribonuclease activity
```

The output I am trying to produce would be

```
GO:0000010     molecular_function
trans-hexaprenyltranstransferase activity
GO:0016765 ! transferase activity, transferring alkyl or aryl (other than methyl) groups

GO:0000011    biological_process
vacuole inheritance
is_a: GO:0007033 ! vacuole organization
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance

GO:0000012    biological_process
single strand break repair
is_a: GO:0006281 ! DNA repair

GO:0000014    molecular_function
single-stranded DNA endodeoxyribonuclease activity
is_a: GO:0004520 ! endodeoxyribonuclease activity
```

The code I have is:

```
import re

id_to_info = {} #declare dictionary

def parse_record(term):
    go_id = re.findall(r"id:\s(.*?)\n", term, re.DOTALL)
    name = re.findall(r"name:\s(.*?)\n", term, re.DOTALL)
    namespace = re.findall(r"namespace:\s(.*?)\n", term, re.DOTALL)
    is_a = re.findall(r"is_a:\s(.*?)\n", term, re.DOTALL)
    info = namespace + "\n" + name + "\n" + is_a
    id_to_info[go_id] = info
    for go_id, info in id_to_info.interitems():
        print(go_id + "\t" + info)

def split_record(record):
    sp_file = open(record)
    sp_records = sp_file.read()
    sp_split_records = re.findall(r"(\[.*?)\n\n", sp_records, re.DOTALL)
    for sp_record in sp_split_records:
        parse_record(term=sp_record)
    sp_file.close()

split_record(record="go.rtf")
```

I don't really know where I am going wrong, but I am thinking the main issue is my dictionary call?

Comment: `id_to_info.interitems():` won't cut it. Try `id_to_info.items():`

Comment: your code crashes for me here: `info = namespace + "\n" + name + "\n" + is_a` because `is_a` is a list.

Comment: ... and what output do you actually get?

Comment: How would be the best way to convert is_a from a list? I tried ''.join(is_a) but it still didn't give any output or errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**re.findall** returns a list of things it found; your code assumes strings.  Since you have only one hit per line, just add **[0]** where feasible.  **is_a** can come back empty, so it needs a little more tender handling.

Also, the (key, value) method is **iteritems** (iteration items), not **i *n* teritems**.

Here's an update:

```
import re

id_to_info = {} #declare dictionary

def parse_record(term):
    go_id = re.findall(r"id:\s(.*?)\n", term, re.DOTALL)[0]
    name = re.findall(r"name:\s(.*?)\n", term, re.DOTALL)[0]
    namespace = re.findall(r"namespace:\s(.*?)\n", term, re.DOTALL)[0]
    is_a = re.findall(r"is_a:\s(.*?)\n", term, re.DOTALL)
    is_a = is_a[0] if is_a else ""
    # print namespace, name, is_a
    info = namespace + "\n" + name + "\n" + is_a
    id_to_info[go_id] = info
    for go_id, info in id_to_info.iteritems():
        print(go_id + "\t" + info)

def split_record(record):
    sp_file = open(record)
    sp_records = sp_file.read()
    sp_split_records = re.findall(r"(\[.*?)\n\n", sp_records, re.DOTALL)
    for sp_record in sp_split_records:
        parse_record(term=sp_record)
    sp_file.close()

split_record(record="go.rtf")
```

Output:

```
GO:0000010  molecular_function
trans-hexaprenyltranstransferase activity
GO:0016765 ! transferase activity, transferring alkyl or aryl (other
GO:0000011  biological_process
vacuole inheritance
GO:0007033 ! vacuole organization
GO:0000010  molecular_function
trans-hexaprenyltranstransferase activity
GO:0016765 ! transferase activity, transferring alkyl or aryl (other
GO:0000011  biological_process
vacuole inheritance
GO:0007033 ! vacuole organization
GO:0000010  molecular_function
trans-hexaprenyltranstransferase activity
GO:0016765 ! transferase activity, transferring alkyl or aryl (other
GO:0000012  biological_process
single strand break repair
```

I'll leave the rest of the formatting to you.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

id_to_info = {} #declare dictionary

def parse_record(term):
    go_id = re.findall(r"id:\s(.*?)\n", term, re.DOTALL)[0]
    name = re.findall(r"name:\s(.*?)\n", term, re.DOTALL)[0]
    namespace = re.findall(r"namespace:\s(.*?)\n", term, re.DOTALL)[0]
    is_a = re.findall(r'is_a:(.*)', term, re.DOTALL)[0]
    info = namespace + "\n" + name + "\n" + is_a
    id_to_info[go_id] = info
    for go_id, info in id_to_info.iteritems():
        print(go_id + "\t" + info)

def split_record(record):
    sp_file = open(record)
    sp_records = sp_file.read()
    sp_split_records = re.findall(r"(\[.*?)\n\n", sp_records, re.DOTALL)
    for sp_record in sp_split_records:
        parse_record(term=sp_record)
    sp_file.close()

split_record(record="go.rtf")
```

I would suggest *NOT* to use IDE, use instead terminal or
at least to debug interpreter:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 18:31:42) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = """[Term]
... id: GO:0000010
... name: trans-hexaprenyltranstransferase activity
... namespace: molecular_function
... def: "Catalysis of the reaction: all-trans-hexaprenyl diphosphate + isopentenyl diphosphate = all-trans-heptaprenyl diphosphate + diphosphate." [KEGG:R05612, RHEA:20839]
... subset: gosubset_prok
... xref: KEGG:R05612
... xref: RHEA:20839
... is_a: GO:0016765 ! transferase activity, transferring alkyl or aryl (other than methyl) groups"""
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'is_a:(.*)', s)
[' GO:0016765 ! transferase activity, transferring alkyl or aryl (other than methyl) groups']
```

Also put lots of print, Python is dynamic, meaning it doesn't have compile and run .. it will run till it hits error.

Your problems:

> 1) RegEx - Google around 
>   2) Typo - iteritems!  Both you can read from
>   Python doc. They are really good.. Or pick any book .. you'll learn a
>   lot while writing code and experimenting on interpreter.

---Python lover!