# Printing dictionary results in multiples

Tags: python, dictionary

I already asked a question about this program [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40941433/compiling-and-iterating-over-a-dictionary/40941771#40941771)

The code I am currently running is

```
import re


out = open("parse_go.txt", "w")

id_to_info = {} #declare dictionary

def parse_record(term):
    go_id = re.findall(r"id:\s(.*?)\n", term, re.DOTALL)[0]
    name = re.findall(r"name:\s(.*?)\n", term, re.DOTALL)[0]
    namespace = re.findall(r"namespace:\s(.*?)\n", term, re.DOTALL)[0]
    is_a = re.findall(r"is_a:\s(.*?)\n", term, re.DOTALL)
    is_a = "\n\t".join(is_a)
    info = namespace + "\n" + "\t" + name + "\n" + "\t" +  is_a
    id_to_info[go_id] = info
    for go_id, info in id_to_info.items():
        out.write(go_id + "\t" + info + "\n\n")
    # for go_id in id_to_info:
    #    out.write(go_id + "\t" + info + "\n\n")        


def split_record(record):
    sp_file = open(record)
    sp_records = sp_file.read()
    sp_split_records = re.findall(r"(\[.*?)\n\n", sp_records, re.DOTALL)
    for sp_record in sp_split_records:
        parse_record(term=sp_record)
    sp_file.close()

split_record(record="/scratch/go-basic.obo")
```

But as you can see from the beginning of the output file I am getting multiple printouts of the same result.

```
GO:0000001      biological_process
        mitochondrion inheritance
        GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance

GO:0000002      biological_process
        mitochondrial genome maintenance


GO:0000001      biological_process
        mitochondrion inheritance
        GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance

GO:0000002      biological_process
        mitochondrial genome maintenance


GO:0000003      biological_process
        reproduction


GO:0000001      biological_process
        mitochondrion inheritance
        GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance

GO:0000005      molecular_function
        ribosomal chaperone activity


GO:0000002      biological_process
        mitochondrial genome maintenance


GO:0000003      biological_process
        reproduction


GO:0000001      biological_process
        mitochondrion inheritance
        GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance
```

The beginning of the input file is as follows, but it is a very large file and takes a long time to run

```
[Term]
id: GO:0000001
name: mitochondrion inheritance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The distribution of mitochondria, including the mitochondrial genome, into daughter cells after mitosis or meiosis, mediated by interactions between mitochondria and the cytoskeleton." [GOC:mcc, PMID:10873824, PMID:11389764]
synonym: "mitochondrial inheritance" EXACT []
is_a: GO:0048308 ! organelle inheritance
is_a: GO:0048311 ! mitochondrion distribution

[Term]
id: GO:0000002
name: mitochondrial genome maintenance
namespace: biological_process
def: "The maintenance of the structure and integrity of the mitochondrial genome; includes replication and segregation of the mitochondrial chromosome." [GOC:ai, GOC:vw]
is_a: GO:0007005 ! mitochondrion organization

[Term]
id: GO:0000003
name: reproduction
namespace: biological_process
alt_id: GO:0019952
alt_id: GO:0050876
def: "The production of new individuals that contain some portion of genetic material inherited from one or more parent organisms." [GOC:go_curators, GOC:isa_complete, GOC:jl, ISBN:0198506732]
subset: goslim_generic
subset: goslim_pir
subset: goslim_plant
subset: gosubset_prok
synonym: "reproductive physiological process" EXACT [] 
xref: Wikipedia:Reproduction
is_a: GO:0008150 ! biological_process

[Term]
id: GO:0000005
name: ribosomal chaperone activity
namespace: molecular_function
def: "OBSOLETE. Assists in the correct assembly of ribosomes or ribosomal subunits in vivo, but is not a component of the assembled ribosome when performing its normal biological function." [GOC:jl, PMID:12150913]
comment: This term was made obsolete because it refers to a class of gene products and a biological process rather than a molecular function.
is_obsolete: true
consider: GO:0042254
consider: GO:0044183
consider: GO:0051082
```

I know the dictionary will not be in numerical order, but I am wondering if the multiple prints like that is expected, or due to some error in my coding?

Comment: Your dict has unique keys by definition (construction). Your `info` values are responsible for the duplication. Is that clear to you? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I was worried it would be because of that, is there a way to remove the duplication?

Comment: I don't really understand what your parsing is doing and what your input is and what the expected output is. My suspicion is that all that regex magic is not doing what you want it do to.

Comment: There is no duplicated keys in your dict. However, you are printing out the dict every time you add a key into your dict (in the for loop, `out.write(go_id + "\t" + info + "\n\n")`). Therefore, you find the duplicates in the output.

Comment: And to parse a GO file in obo format, I would recommend to use an existing Obo parser package to extract the information. Check http://pythonhosted.org/Orange-Bioinformatics/reference/ontology.html for example.